# Property 'seriesDataItem' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: javascript, angular, amcharts, amcharts4

I have this code in JS and I need to make it work in TypeScript.

```
   series2.events.on("dataitemsvalidated", function() {
      var data = [];
      series2.dataItems.each(function(dataItem) {
        data.push({ name: dataItem.categoryY +": " + dataItem.valueX + "%", fill: dataItem.column.fill, seriesDataItem: dataItem })
      })
      chart.legend.data = data;


      chart.legend.itemContainers.template.events.on("toggled", function(event) {
        var seriesDataItem = event.target.dataItem.dataContext.seriesDataItem;
        console.log(seriesDataItem)
        if (event.target.isActive) {
          seriesDataItem.hide(series2.interpolationDuration, 0, 0, ["valueX"]);
        }
        else {
          seriesDataItem.show(series2.interpolationDuration, 0, ["valueX"]);
        }
      })
    })
```

This function i used in Amchart and it has an issue with this line `event.target.dataItem.dataContext.seriesDataItem`

Comment: did you try casting the `event.target.dataItem.dataContext` to any ?

Comment: I tried var seriesDataItem:any = event.target.dataItem.dataContext.seriesDataItem        But it didnt worked.

Comment: the same error output ?

Comment: Yes, same......

Comment: did you try to `console.log(event.target.dataItem.dataContext)` ?

Comment: Using `ISpritePointerEvent` for an XY chart though but I have the same issue. `@ts-ignore` is the way to go for me.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the type of `event` to `any` should work:

```
chart.legend.itemContainers.template.events.on("toggled", function(event:any) {})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
const ctx = event.target.dataItem.dataContext as any;
const seriesDataItem = ctx && ctx.seriesDataItem;
```

So you can then use the right interface for your event, see [amcharts4](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/pointevent/) or [amcharts5](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/reference/tag/interface/).